# 2 external USB monitors on MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, display, usb

I have a new macbook pro, got it in january of 2014. I am trying to connect 2 USB ASUS MB168B monitors via the separate USB ports on my macbook pro. One will load up and they other one goes black. The system preferences recognizes that there are 3 displays but one of them is completely blacked out. I know both monitors work because when i only plug one or the other, they work fine, however when i try to have both plugged in, one goes black outed (the first one i plug in gets overridden by the second one)

thoughts?

Comment: What software or drivers let the USB device become a display? Also, what version of OS X and any other software is involved.

Answer (score 1):

My knee-jerk thought is insufficient power to supply both monitors (hence why connecting either singularly works without issue).  I know the default for those monitors is bus-powered, do they have an option for an external power supply?  Or can you try then through a powered USB hub?